# Gradle Could not find method “() for arguments on root project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle project that I'm attempting to fix and am slowly learning Gradle's syntax as I go.

Currently I have a library that if `IS_RELEASE` (an environmental variable) is set, then it uploads it to our production servers. If not, it copies it to our testing location.

The code is as follows:

```
task(detect) << {
    if(System.getenv().containsKey("IS_RELEASE"))
        apply from: “{$rootDir}/upload-pack.gradle”
    else
        apply from: “{$rootDir}/copy-testing.gradle”
}

detect.mustRunAfter build
build.finalizedBy detect
```

The code looks just fine and doesn't cause any syntax errors in NetBeans. However, when I run `gradle build` I get the following:

> :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>       :processResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :classes UP-TO-DATE
>       :jar UP-TO-DATE
>       :assemble UP-TO-DATE
>       :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
>       :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>       :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
>       :test UP-TO-DATE
>       :check UP-TO-DATE
>       :build UP-TO-DATE
>       :detect FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Build file '/path/to/gradle/project/build.gradle' line: 62
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':detect'.
>     Could not find method “() for arguments [build_934uxjujs447ej84orspcupbq$_run_closure4$_closure15@3a230b5f] on root project 'myproject'.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
>   BUILD FAILED

Line 62 is `apply from: “{$rootDir}/copy-testing.gradle”`.

Am I missing something here? I have taken some similar ideas from [here](http://gradle.org/blog/gradle-the-build-system-for-android/) and fixed the solutions up. (See the "Apply From a File" header.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your quotation marks are wrong.
In your code you are using (copied from the linked website) `“` and `”` (Double curved quotes) instead of regular (ambidextrous) "s.

Comment: Aha, misleading characters strike again :P Thank you for pointing that out to me, after I changed it it worked! I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Great, feel free to click the check icon next to my answer ;)

Comment: Can single quotes be used here?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Sure, just make sure to use the right ones `'` (Apostrophes)